# how to parse XML?

Tags: nsmutablearray, nsxmlparser

when i am parsing the following i got some errors.
There is no String value at Verse didEndEelement..
I need Chapters in one Mutable Array.. please help me.

```
<book name="Genesis">
    <chapter number="1"> Name of the chapter </chapter>
    <chapter number="1"> Name of the chapter </chapter>
     <chapter number="1"> Name of the chapter </chapter>
  </book>

  <book name="Genesis">
    <chapter number="1"> Name of the chapter </chapter>
    <chapter number="1"> Name of the chapter </chapter>
     <chapter number="1"> Name of the chapter </chapter>
  </book>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see topsongs sample of apple in developer center or find on google about how to parse xml using nsxml parser. you can also use some different xml parser search on google for that. you will definitely find one